# Finish partition from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, partitioning

I was trying to make a partition on my 1TB drive for installing Ubuntu 14.04. I had to remove an older partition in order to do it from my old Elementary OS distro. As I was restarting my computer and wiping the old partition I accidentally erased the Windows bootloader. As result my Windows can't boot. My problem with this is the partition I intend to install Ubuntu on. I'm using `EaseUS` to "cut" 50GB for Ubuntu. When I restarted my computer in order to apply the settings the error with the bootloader occurred and I don't know if the partition is actually ready to install Ubuntu.

[image]

(I’m working from "Try Ubuntu" right now.)

As you can see I have 3 drives.
⠀One 80GB for the Windows 8
⠀The master storage which the partition is based
⠀and the Ubuntu partition on which I want to install Ubuntu.

Is it possible to see if the partition is safe?

Comment: Post gparted image

Comment: what do you mean by cut 50 GB for Ubuntu. Did you tried to take space from windows 8 partition.

Comment: I'm having 2 disks. One 80GB for Windows and one 1TB for general use. I wanted to cut a 50GB from the 1TB

Answer (score 0):

First repair your windows boot loader and after that install Ubuntu.

To fix windows, boot from windows cd/usb.
Go to **Repair -> repair** using Command prompt and enter the below commands.

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

It will restore the system partition.

After that you may try to partition the drive from windows and then proceed to install Ubuntu on your created partition, or use Gparted from Ubuntu live cd/usb; for more details refer to [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)